# Moving Shape on Drag Javafx - Shape Keeps Resetting

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get a simple rectangle to move on drag. I have it moving, but when I try to drag again, it first reverts back to the initial position before the initial drag. I've tried using StackPane, FlowPane, Pane, and AnchorPane.

```
  public View getView() {
        View view = new View("Test View");
        view.setName(name);
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        rect.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
            xVal = me.getSceneX();
            yVal = me.getSceneY();
            System.out.println("PRESSED_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
        });

        rect.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent me) -> {
            System.out.println("RELEASE_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
        });

        rect.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) ->{
            final double diffX = me.getSceneX() - xVal;
            final double diffY = me.getSceneY() - yVal;
            System.out.println("SET_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
            rect.setX(diffX);
            rect.setY(diffY);
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        view.setCenter(pane);
        return view;
    }
```

**Note:** `rect`,`xVal`,`yVal` are all class properties.

The issue again is that I can move the rectangle just fine. However when I try to move again, the rectangle seems to jump back to the original point of the rectangle. You can see in the following image where it seems to revert:

[image: Rectangle On Drag Issue]

**Note:** The fact that the `diffX` and `diffY` are `final` isn't a problem here.

**Another Note:** I have also tried `setTranslate()` as well as `getTransforms().add()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I was fiddling around with it and I figured it out that every time I press down, the X and Y coordinates of the rectangle are calibrated at `(0,0)`. So all I had to do was to set `xVal` and `yVal` to 0 in the initial mouse press event. However, this makes`xVal` and `yVal` to be trivial. Thus, they can be deleted.  Not really sure if this was the best solution, but it works for me:

```
    rect.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
        System.out.println("PRESSED_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
    });

    rect.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent me) -> {
        System.out.println("RELEASE_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
    });

    rect.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) ->{
        double diffX = me.getX() - rect.getWidth() / 2;
        double diffY = me.getY() - rect.getHeight() / 2;
        System.out.println("SET_" + Double.toString(rect.getX()));
        rect.setX(diffX);
        rect.setY(diffY);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you can remove xVal and yVal.